# How To Use Select2 As Searchable Dropdown or Textbox At The Same Time?

Tags: jquery, textbox, asp.net-core-mvc, full-text-search, jquery-select2

I am working on a text messaging application where I have to maintain a table for Contacts where Contact names, Phone, and other fields are stored. I am using the .Net Core 5.0 Framework with SQL server database.

What I want is to add a search functionality when I want to send a new message. I have two scenarios here.

1. To send a new message to existing contact (Phone number already saved in my database).
2. To send a new message to a new number (Not saved in my database).

I have added the jQuery Search2 library and can search existing contacts by Name or by Phone number and I can send a new message to existing contacts like a pro.

However, I want to use or configure the same Search2 dropdown so it can act like a textbox when I type in a new phone number that is not saved in my database and it can maintain this number as a value. Upon clicking on the send message button, this new number should be passed as the textbox value to my controller.

For now, when I click outside the search2 control after typing in the phone number, it resets the value to null.

Here is my select2 HTML:

```
<select id="ajaxSelect2" class="js-data-example-ajax"></select>
```

And the jQuery code goes here:

```
$("#ajaxSelect2").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "https://localhost:44343/api/Contact/Search",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            var query =
            {
                term: params.term,
            };
            return query;
        },
        processResults: function (result) {
            debugger
            return {
                results: $.map(result, function (item) {
                    return {
                        id: item.phoneNo,
                        text: item.firstName + ' ' + item.lastName
                    };
                }),
            }
        },
        cache: true
    },
    placeholder: 'Search Contacts or Type In Phone Number',
    allowClear: true,
    minimumInputLength: 1
});
```

Is there any possibility for allowing/customizing Search2 control as per my requirements so it can act as a dropdown as well as a textbox at the same time?

Any expert suggestion will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found any configuration in select2 can realize your feature, therefore I tried to write custom code to reach it. My idea is save the `params.term` into a global variable, then we check if there's data existing in the query result by ajax, if it returns no options, we set the `params.term` as the innerHTML of the select input. And then it can solve the problem that you click the empty place of the page and the input value turns null;

```
data: function(params) {
    selectVal = params.term;
    var query = {
        search: params.term,
        type: 'public'
    }
    return query;
},
processResults: function(result) {
    if(result.result.length == 0){
        document.getElementsByClassName('select2-selection__rendered')[0].innerHTML=selectVal;
    }
    return {
        results: result.result
    };
},
```